# Print pandas dataframes in the python console with a right shift (white spaces)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to print arrays, pandas dataframes or even some commands, leaving systematic white spaces before (the goal is to have a nice looking logfile). Anyone knows how to achieve that in a elegant way (without looping) ?

What I have:

```
print('  * PR data types :')
print(df_PR.dtypes)

  * PR data types :
Date              datetime64[ns]
U                        float64
pH                       float64
eH                       float64
FreeAcidity              float64
Fe2                      float64
Fe3                      float64
SO4                      float64
Ca                       float64
Cl                       float64
Mg                       float64
Al                       float64
Total_Salinity           float64
MES                      float64
dtype: object
```

What I would like:

```
   * PR data types :
   Date              datetime64[ns]
   U                        float64 
   pH                       float64
   eH                       float64
   FreeAcidity              float64
   Fe2                      float64
   Fe3                      float64
   SO4                      float64
   Ca                       float64
   Cl                       float64
   Mg                       float64
   Al                       float64
   Total_Salinity           float64
   MES                      float64
   dtype: object
```

Comment: Is the stuff under what you want a table?

Comment: No necessarily a table, just a clean print, with four spaces.

Comment: In that case, @Renaud 's answer should work.

Answer (score 1):

It's maybe not the best way todo it but you can do like that:

```
print('  * PR data types :')
for index,types in df_PR.dtypes.iteritems():
    print(f"\t{index}\t{types}")
```

Comment: Well, this is with a for-loop :(, but yes it works !